# Refresh a tcxgrid without losing the current row selected/highlighted

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

Using Delphi XE2.

I have a tcxgrid which is connected to a datasource, which is looking at a table in a database, the cxgrid is displaying fields and records from within that table.

Does anyone know how to Refresh the tcxgrid without losing the current row selected?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "refresh" please

Comment: Please edit the question to provide all the details we need to be clear as to what you are asking. Thank you.

Comment: If I understood you correctly (as @DavidHeffernan says there is too few information) you are looking for [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q473501).

Answer (score 0):

To restore the selection you can use `cxStatusKeeper` (it's a public unit that you can download from the support center of DevExpress):

```
{Init the component for restore selection}
FGridStatus := TcxGridDBTableKeeper.Create(self);
FGridStatus.LoadExpanding   := False;
FGridStatus.LoadSelection   := True;
FGridStatus.LoadFocus       := True;
FGridStatus.LoadTopRecord   := False;
FGridStatus.LoadWithDetails := False;
FGridStatus.LoadFocusedView := True;
FGridStatus.LoadFocusedItem := True;
FGridStatus.View            := gvTableElementi;

{save the current items} 
FGridStatus.Store;

{restore the selection}   
if FGridStatus.GridStored then
  FGridStatus.Restore;
```